# Regex to match path except file and its parent directory

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying write an expression that matches a filepath but exclude the filename and its parent directory. This is my test string:

```
file/in/some/dir1/file1.txt
file/in/some/dir2/file1.txt
file/in/some/dir2/file2.txt
file/in/some/other/dir/file1.txt
```

what I want the regex to match is:

```
file/in/some
file/in/some
file/in/some
file/in/some/other
```

---

I tried different kinds of negative look-aheads but I didn't succeed. All I could come up with is an expression that matches the exact opposite of my desired match: `(\w+\/\w+\.\w+)`. With this I get the filename and it's parent directory but I don't know how to "invert" the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close with your "matches the exact opposite" regex, you just need to capture the *other* part of the string:

```
m{(.*)/\w+/\w+\.\w+$}
```

I've also modified it so that the non-captured part of the match has to start with a `/` (otherwise it gave wrong results), used `m{}` instead of `//` to delimit the regex so that the `/` characters in the regex don't need to be escaped (`\/` - "leaning toothpick syndrome"), and anchored it to the end of the string (so that it will still work correctly if one of the directory names contains a `.`).

Full test implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @paths = qw(
  file/in/some/dir1/file1.txt
  file/in/some/dir2/file1.txt
  file/in/some/dir2/file2.txt
  file/in/some/other/dir/file1.txt
);

for my $path (@paths) {
  $path =~ m{(.*)/\w+/\w+\.\w+$};
  say $1;
}
```

Output:

```
file/in/some
file/in/some
file/in/some
file/in/some/other
```

Answer (score 0):

The file or directory name can never contain a slash. So the last two parts of the path are `/[^/]+/[^/]+$`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More tests => 4;

my %test = (
    'file/in/some/dir1/file1.txt'      => 'file/in/some',
    'file/in/some/dir2/file1.txt'      => 'file/in/some',
    'file/in/some/dir2/file2.txt'      => 'file/in/some',
    'file/in/some/other/dir/file1.txt' => 'file/in/some/other');

for my $path (keys %test) {
    is match($path), $test{$path}, $path;
}

sub match {
    my ($path) = @_;
    return ($path =~ m{(.*)/[^/]+/[^/]+$})[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s~/[^/]+/[^/]+$~~;
    say;
}

__DATA__
file/in/some/dir1/file1.txt
file/in/some/dir2/file1.txt
file/in/some/dir2/file2.txt
file/in/some/other/dir/file1.txt
```

**Output:**

```
file/in/some
file/in/some
file/in/some
file/in/some/other
```

Comment: Note that this version, because it uses `s///` (well, `s~~~`) instead of `m//`, will modify the original strings, which may or may not be appropriate in the OP's use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex, with just 1 parameter, to change how many directories above you want to get.
Change the value inside "{x,}", the higher the number, the more directories you go up.

```
/(.*)(?:(?:\/[^/]+){2,})/g
```

So with the regex above, do a replace and use group 1 (like $1 or \1). The results will be these:

```
file/in/some/dir1
file/in/some/dir2
file/in/some/dir2
file/in/some/other
```

You can use in shell like (note that the non-capturing group "?:" doesn't work in the shell):

```shell
$ realpath /etc/alternatives/java
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

$ realpath /etc/alternatives/java | sed -E 's/(.*)((\/[^/]+){2,})/\1/g'
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64
```

This can be used in .bashrc, for example to define the JAVA_HOME path, without needing to specify exactly the package version.

```bash
export JAVA_HOME="$(realpath /etc/alternatives/java | sed -E 's/(.*)((\/[^/]+){2,})/\1/g')"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [File::Basename](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) module comes with Perl:

```
use v5.10;
use File::Basename;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say dirname( dirname($_) );
    }

__DATA__
file/in/some/dir1/file1.txt
file/in/some/dir2/file1.txt
file/in/some/dir2/file2.txt
file/in/some/other/dir/file1.txt
```

That example works with whatever paths are ntive to that system, so
it would handle Windows paths run on Windows. It can even

```
use v5.10;
use File::Basename;

# on unix, but want to deal with Windows paths
fileparse_set_fstype('MSWin32');
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say dirname( dirname($_) );
    }

__DATA__
file\in\some\dir1\file1.txt
file\in\some\dir2\file1.txt
file\in\some\dir2\file2.txt
file\in\some\other\dir\file1.txt
```

There are other modules, such as [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) or [Mojo::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::File) that can do the same things.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another approach assuming all data is in a string and using a lookahead regexp:

```
my $files = "1: file/in/some/dir1/file1.txt
2: file/in/some/dir2/file1.txt
3: file/in/some/dir2/file2.txt
4: file/in/some/other/dir/file1.txt";
my @dirs = $files =~ m{((?:\w+/)+)(?=\w+\/\w+\.\w+)}g;
say for @dirs;
```

**Output**:

```
file/in/some/
file/in/some/
file/in/some/
file/in/some/other/
```